# How FanDuel aligns their sports lines like this?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm learning SwiftUI and my practice project is a sportsbook similar to FanDuel, DraftKings, etc... I just started working on the lines part of it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLIg8.jpg).

I understand the concept of stacks, but not so much the aligning within them. [This is how mine turned out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S3i8.png)

As you can see, both stacks are not aligned. I would like to keep the 9 buttons in a fixed position, and keep everything aligned regardless of the length of the team names, how FanDuel does. Any help would be awesome!

Below is my code.

```
ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 125)
                
                HStack {
                    VStack(spacing: 13) {
                        HStack {
                            Image("ny")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            Text("NY Islanders")
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Image("tb")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            Text("TB Lightning")
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }

                        
                    }
                    .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("-1.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-120")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("+1.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("+135")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("-121")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("+102")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("O 5.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-110")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("U 5.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-102")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 125)
                
                HStack {
                    VStack(spacing: 13) {
                        HStack {
                            Image("atl")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            Text("ATL Hawks")
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        
                        HStack {
                            Image("phi")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            Text("PHI 76ers")
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }

                        
                    }
                    .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 50)
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("-1.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-120")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("+1.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("+135")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("-121")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("+102")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("O 5.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-110")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("U 5.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-102")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `VStack`'s `alignment` to `.leading`. This will make both `HStack`s stick to the left side.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 13) { /// here!
    HStack {
        Image("ny")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        Text("NY Islanders")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    HStack {
        Image("tb")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        Text("TB Lightning")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

Also, remove the `width: .infinity` from the rectangle - you'll get a warning that it's not allowed.

```
Rectangle()
    .stroke(Color.black)
    .frame(height: 125) /// remove the width
```

Result:

[image: Stacks that contain team names are aligned left]

Full code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(Color.black)
                    .frame(height: 125) /// remove the width
                
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 13) { /// here!
                        HStack {
                            Image("ny")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            Text("NY Islanders")
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Image("tb")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            Text("TB Lightning")
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("-1.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-120")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("+1.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("+135")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("-121")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("+102")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("O 5.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-110")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("U 5.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-102")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(Color.black)
                    .frame(height: 125)
                
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 13) { /// and here!
                        HStack {
                            Image("atl")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            Text("ATL Hawks")
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        
                        HStack {
                            Image("phi")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            Text("PHI 76ers")
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 50)
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("-1.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-120")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("+1.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("+135")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("-121")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("+102")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("O 5.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-110")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text("U 5.5")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                        
                                        Text("-102")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .font(.caption2)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                }
                            })
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response! Worked perfectly. How can I also align the hstack of the 9 buttons?

Comment: @phast just replace the `Spacer()` that comes right after the `HStack` with some padding.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me. They're still off by a bit. To reiterate, I'm trying to stack both sets of 9 buttons with each other. It gets off balance once I change the names of the NBA teams because they are shorter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I actually figured it out.. just added a frame around the team images & names stack and it aligned the buttons evenly